# Removing stylesheets issues (wp_dequeue_style)

Tags: optimization, python-requests, stylesheet

I'm having trouble removing (wp_dequeue_style) all the stylesheets loaded in a WP site. 
I want to remove all the styles loaded, with the purpose of recreating a new style that can be better controlled and optimized and **reduce 68 requests to 1**.

But before I get further into this, I'll say a bit about the tools used.

I'm using Wordpress v5.4.1 on a server with Apache 7.2.30. The WP theme is MasterStudy Child and the plugins used are as follows:

- Breadcrumb NavXT
- BuddyPress
- Contact Form 7
- GamiPress
- GTmetrix for WordPress
- WPBakery Page Builder
- MasterStudy LMS Learning Management System PRO
- MasterStudy LMS
- Paid Memberships Pro
- Slider Revolution
- GDPR Compliance & Cookie Consent
- STM Configurations
- Transients Manager
- UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore
- WooCommerce
- WordPress Importer
- WP Reset
- Query Monitor

I can get a list of all enqueued CSS stylesheets using 3 methods:
1. Chrome Inspector - Network tab
2. Query Monitor 
3. The script bellow, used in functions.php of parent theme

```
function remove_theme_head_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    echo "<h2>Enqueued CSS Stylesheets</h2>";
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) :
        echo $handle . ", ";
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_theme_head_styles', 9000 );
```

The results are as follows:

**Method 1** (Chrome): 68 requests, though some are duplicates

**Method 2** (Query Monitor): 66 Styles

**Method 3** (php script): 52 results

Next, lets switch from listing all the enqueued CSS files, to removing them with this script

```
function remove_theme_head_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) :
        wp_dequeue_style( $handle );
        wp_deregister_style( $handle );
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_theme_head_styles', 9000 );
```

Let's see what we have now:

**Method 2** (Query Monitor): 13 styles - all of them loaded in the footer. 10 of them are coming from the parent theme and the other 3 from the theme's main plugin MasterStudy LMS

**Method 1** (chrome): 14 requests, same as QM except for 1 extra font family CSS

**Method 3** (php script echo): 0 results

So, maybe we need to change the hook, go further down the hooks order, to also include the stylesheets enqueued in the footer.
Let's try *wp_print_footer_scripts* with a big number for priority

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'remove_theme_head_styles', 9000 );
```

The results are: 
**Method 1** (chrome): 65 requests, WTF? almost all of them have loaded!

**Method 2** (Query Monitor): 0 Styles

Method 3 (php script): 0 results - same hook used for listing, wp_print_footer_scripts

And YES the webpage has rendered accordingly, so the Chrome Inspector is not wrong, but this doesn't mean that the other 2 methods have false results. It just means that the CSS files are re-enqueued after the results of methods 2 and 3 are generated
But how is this happening I cannot understand.

I have also tried splitting the removal process into 2 hooks, 1 with wp_enqueue_scripts and another with different hooks like wp_footer and such, but with no success

The 10 'trouble' styles coming from the theme itself, are loaded with this function

themes/masterstudy/inc/custom.php

```
function stm_module_styles($handle, $style = 'style_1', $deps = array(), $inline_styles = '')
{
    $path = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/vc_modules/' . $handle . '/' . $style . '.css';
    $handle = 'stm-' . $handle . '-' . $style;
    wp_enqueue_style($handle, $path, $deps, STM_THEME_VERSION, 'all');

    if (!empty($inline_styles)) wp_add_inline_style($handle, $inline_styles);
}
```

Here's an example of using the function above

themes/masterstudy/vc_templates/stm_mailchimp.php

```
stm_module_styles('mailchimp', 'style_1', array(), $inline_styles);
```

Obviously, if I comment that line then the CSS won't be loaded, but this is not the approach I want to take to solving the problem.

So, if anyone can offer some help, it would be much appreciated

Thanks for taking the time and reading through this

Answer (score 1):

The below is likely not a great approach, but I recently needed to prevent VC from loading the free version of FontAwesome (I use the pro version in my theme) and no amount of dequeue/deregister would work - the below is the only way I could stop it loading (without editing files outside my theme).

The thing that actually worked, was brutally unsetting the entry in wp_styles.

```
function hack_dequeue_fa() {
    global $wp_styles;

    $remove = array(
      'vc_font_awesome_5',
      'vc_font_awesome_5_shims',
    );

    foreach($remove as $handle) {
      wp_dequeue_style($handle);
      wp_deregister_script($handle);
      unset($wp_styles->registered[$handle]);
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hack_dequeue_fa', PHP_INT_MAX );
```